# Single MySQL query to get result from diffrent tables based on no of views

Tags: mysql

Hi i know basic MySQL query format, but now i have a need to do some complex query.
say (for explanation purpose)
i have 3 tables with column **id**, **item_name**, and **no_of_views**.
i want to a single query to get top 10 viewed items from these 3 table.

```
Table1

 id:        item_name        no_of_views
 1          item1             20
 2          item2             25
 3          item3             16
 4          item4             10

Table2

 id:        item_name        no_of_views
 1          itemA             2
 2          itemB             5
 3          itemC             70
 4          itemD             0

Table3

 id:        item_name        no_of_views
 1          item_1             34
 2          item_2             55
 3          item_3             10
 4          item_4             1
```

i know i have to join these tables and then query based on no_of views

like

```
 $query="
 (SELECT * FROM Table2)
 UNION ALL
 (SELECT * FROM Table2)
 UNION ALL
 (SELECT * FROM Table2)
 ORDER by no_of _views DESC LIMIT 10";
```

This works perfectly fine but my problem is my tables have 100's of item in them and i have many tables, if this is the way i do it the query will have to get all the results from all the tables and then give me only top 10 views,

i want to do it like selecting only 10 values from all tables based on no of views 
like say i have 10 tables and each one have a no_of_views, how can i query to see which item has higest views among all tables and then next lower no_of_views from another table or same table which ever is true and so on.
is that even possible.

please suggest.

Comment: "f this is the way i do it the query will have to get all the results from all the tables and then give me only top 10 views" - this is the main problem of such a query - the SQL engine can't know what the top ten views are until it has viewed all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing your query to the following query, the MySQL Execution plans are identical. The optimizer will still only be selecting the top 10 from each table **(not the full record set)** and then comparing them as that is the maximum it will need. This method is not as inefficient as you seem to believe.

```
$query="
(SELECT * FROM Table1 ORDER BY no_of_views DESC LIMIT 10)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM Table2 ORDER BY no_of_views DESC LIMIT 10)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM Table3 ORDER BY no_of_views DESC LIMIT 10)
ORDER by no_of _views DESC LIMIT 10";
```

Comment: ya i know i have to go like this.